# How can I get an image to vertically align with text consitently across multiple browsers?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, html

I'm trying to make a "reply" button on my website which will have a drop down box next to it for specifying additional options. Sort of like this: [Reply][v] 
I was able to create the "Reply" button ok but I'm having problems with the additional options button: I can't seem to get the image I want to use for it consistently centered across multiple browsers. For instance, firefox moves the image down while chrome has the image up higher. (I added red lines to the picture below to show the spacing inconsistency)
[Link](http://home.comcast.net/~ano316gamer/ffcompp.PNG) to show issue: 

Does anyone know how I can get this image properly vertically centered (horizontally it works fine!) within the span or have another suggestion as to how I can make my button? It's also important that the "arrow" button have the same height as the "Reply" button (well their outer borders at least) as some solutions I have tried have caused that to "break". I would also like to keep the arrow button image as part of an element's "background" property so that it can be selected from a png which contains multiple images. (for efficiency reasons so only one image is loaded for all icons on the site)
 I know I sound picky about this one pixel skew, but the problem seems to get worse depending on the line-height I'm using and really causes it to look bad. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

```
<div>
    <a href="#" class="link1"><span class="text">Reply</span></a><a href="#" class="link2"><span class="options"></span></a>
</div>

.link1{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.link2{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    border-left: none;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.text{
    margin: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.options{
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
    padding: 0px 5px 0px 12px;
    background-image: url("arrow.png");
    background-position: 2px 3px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: This answer should provide your solution perfectly:

http://stackoverflow.com/a/5680474/175082

Comment: This won't work because I would need to put the <div> (a block element) which contains the image inside an <a> (an inline element) in order to make the whole box clickable and not just the image. Also, I need a solution which uses the image as the background of a <span> (so the picture I want can be selected out of multiple in the same image file) and not make use of the <img> tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use different styles/stylesheets for different browsers with the various available methods, or you can set one height, and use `position: absolute`. I find most of the time, `position: absolute;` does a good job fixing things across many browsers. for example

```
position: absolute;
top: 10px;
left: 100px;
```

this moves the image 10 pixels down, and 100px right (relative to the closest parent element that is **not** `position: fixed;`